# Uniform load applied to a parabolic curve

Tags: calculus

As I have to design the [vertebra bone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cervical_vertebrae) and its natural boundary conditions I came across a problem.

How can I applied a uniform load if the place where the force is applied is a parabolic curve.

Ok so I get the curve will have this value
$$y(x) = -y_1/x_1 \cdot x^2 + y_1$$

So I did the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to discover the tangent of the curve so it can be possible to calculate the normal force so I can apply the normal force to the surface.

My question is how is it applied to the surface?

Comment: Not enough information to answer. Uniform and normal to the curvature of the spine or uniform parallel to the direction of gravity (i.e. the weight of each vertebra)

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Your question still is not obvious to me. You used a 2D function to discribe your 3D bone. Are you asking for the normal force, which is applied to a 2D bone?

Comment: I'm using a two dimensional plate and constantly remodelling the bone taking the small values of density till I arrive to the trabecular disposition like in a RX. but now I have to impose the natural boundary conditions and I have some difficulty cuz I don't know how to applied this force. the force is uniform they all have q0 value and they follow the curve (uniform and normal to the curvature of the spine)

Comment: this picture illustrates the force and how it has to be applied [imageshack](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/semttuloizd.jpg/)